# Multiple Instances of variables

Tags: c#, variables

I am relatively new to c# and I've hit a bit of a bump in the road, and i do not know of a way to do this. an Example to my problem would be:

There are 30 people, each person has a name unique to him/her, and an age unique to him/her.

Is there a way to create a "person" and have multiple instances each containing different variable values without having to declare individual variables for person1name-person30name person1age-person30age...

The reason I'm asking this is because if said "person" has more than 10 or 20 different variables associated with it then that can be up to 300 to 600 individually declared variables...

i hope this made sense as I'm not very good at explaining these sort of things..

Comment: You want a list of classes.

Comment: Are you new to Object Oriented Programming?  `Person` would be a [`class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx)  with several properties (Name, Age, etc), and you can have as many instances as you want (each with its own data)

Comment: You're question is a good question, but it's way too broad. You kind of just asked "what is object oriented programming?" Explaining the concept of classes, objects, and collections to you isn't something you're going to get in a quick question here. I'd recommend you buy a C# book or go through a bunch of OOP tutorials online. It will help clear things up.

Comment: So what your saying is instead of listing variables i would list a class which declared the viariables?

Comment: @XanLV More or less - you would "define" a class and create several instances (putting them in a list if you want, but it's not required,

Comment: If you are new to OOP and C# study up on classes, instances, and variables.

Comment: _putting them in a list if you want, but it's not required_ Well for hundreds of instances it is __highly__ recommended..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a class to hold your "Person" object:

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
```

And then you need to create a list of those `Person` objects somewhere. To create a lot of them, you create a `List` or other collection type object.

```
    public void SomeCreationMethod()
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", ID = "ABC123" });
        people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Jane", LastName = "Doe", ID = "ABC124" });
        people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Jack", LastName = "Doe", ID = "ABC125" });
        people.Add(new Person() { FirstName = "Jill", LastName = "Doe", ID = "ABC126" });
    }
```

The `Person` objects could be read out of a database, text file, network service, etc. You can then refer to them by index. If you want to refer to them by some other kind of identifier, you can create a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Person> people = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
people.Add("ABC123", new Person() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", ID = "ABC123" });
```

Which you then can get back out using:

```
var johnDoe = people["ABC123"];
```

You should read up on object oriented programming and collections.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/219869/Object-Oriented-Programming-in-Csharp-NET
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybcx56wz.aspx

Comment: 1) it should be mentioned that in addition to the fields (data) a class can also have methods (abilities) and also one or more constructors - 2) the `people` List is out of scope and lost after the `SomeCreationMethod` call ..

Comment: @TaW , Its just a quick example, I didn't want to get into a "fundamentals of programming" lesson, which is why I gave the links. Leave your comment up though so the OP can see that.

Answer (score 0):

First I'd recommend you to google [Object Oriented Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd460654.aspx) and learn about the different aspects of it. I'll try to summarize your question though.

Think of a person as an individual object. The unique name and age are like the variables. You can `get()` the persons values. Think of `getters` as a way of asking the person, "What is your name?" or "What is your (insert data)?"

You also need a way to "Create" your person. This is done with `Constructors` and my little snippet is where you set your name and age to specific values. You can have multiple constructors provided the parameters differ in some way shape or form. Example being `Person(string, int)` and then having one be `Person(string, string)`...etc.

```
public class Person
{
    private string _name;
    private int _age;
    //more variables

    Person(string name, int age)
    {
        this._name = name;
        this._age = age;
    }

    public int GetAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    //... more getters. NOTE there is a way of doing this called "Accessors"

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can go out and do multiple instances of each person.

```
Person p1 = new Person("Mark", 15);
Person p2 = new Person("Mark", 24);
Person p3 = new Person("Henry", 12);
```

You have three different `Person`s through instances of the object. A great method of storage now would be to use a list of persons aka people. This could be done with a `List<Person> t = new List<Person>();` I'll let you look up how to add and remove from lists... etc. But this is your question sort of mapped out for your basic understanding and personal tool as you research more about OOP. Cheers.

Comment: In the spirit of not setting him off on the wrong path, I would advise to correctly case the method names (Java uses that notation, C# should not). Also method parameters should be fully named, using `n` and `a` are highly frowned upon unless using as an indexer and only if the meaning is apparent. Should also show that `getAge` should be a property with a `get` accessor, not its own method.

Comment: I always mix them up. Thanks for pointing that out. This is how I was taught from an early stage. Thanks for the criticism though I appreciate it.

Comment: *Constructive* criticism, no intent of putting you down just pointing out best practices.

Comment: @RonBeyer It's very difficult to give my emotional state through strictly text. I understood your intentions completely. Thank you!